# Not able to set custom fonts in WatchKit

Tags: ios, uifont, watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to set Roboto font and have added as target for watch kit extension, but it is still coming as nil. Can we set custom fonts in watch kit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use custom fonts in WatchKit

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html

Comment: Whilst it says it should work, I'm not having any luck either. And yes fonts added to both Targets, and pList updated etc.

Comment: OK, I missed this bit from the documentation:

"Glances and notifications cannot use custom fonts."

Answer (score 8):

Its worked for me.. Using following Codes.

Add the custom Font to both **WatchKit Extension** and **WatchKit App** target **Info.plist**

[image]

Now you write the code following way,

```
   NSMutableAttributedString *attString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString: @"Yano rocks! Always"];

    [attString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:20.0]} range:NSMakeRange(0, attString.string.length)];

    [self.loadingLabel setAttributedText:attString];
```

Comment: Remember although custom fonts can be used in the main watch app, they cannot be used in Glances or Notifications views.

Comment: the answer has a slight problem - I get this error so I gad to fix it - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'

Comment: How do I know the font name I have to use? I imported a file with the filename "courier-new.ttf" which I found at the net. Where do I see the correct name for the parameter fontWithName.

Comment: @Ron Wood, you can run the app with print(UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName("Courier New")). Then the font name will be printed to the debug console. I gave more details in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147102/watchkit-wkinterfacelabel-cant-change-font/28290470#28290470