# How to use a monospaced font in WatchKit

Tags: ios, fonts, watchkit

In my WatchKit layout I need to have a monospaced font. Do I have to add a monospaced font or is there any trick to use the system font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add it manually. Apple has some good instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH19-SW4) in the programming guide. Additionally, here are a couple other threads that have a bit more trouble shooting detail.

- [Setting custom fonts in WatchKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360752/1342462)
- [Setting the font in a WKInterfaceLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147102/watchkit-wkinterfacelabel-cant-change-font)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system font (San Fransisco) which has a monospaced variant.

For `WKInterfaceLabel`, this is not a visible option in interface builder, and you cannot access the `font` property, so you must use an attributed string to set it:

```
UIFont *monospacedFont = [UIFont monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize:36.0 weight:UIFontWeightRegular];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"12:34:56"
                                                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: monospacedFont}];
[self.label setAttributedText:attributedString];
```